# Create a video using processing opengl

Tags: java, api, processing, jmf

I am creating a `REST API` to generate video dynamically based on user input and provided animation types. So, I am using processing 2.2.1 for this.
I want to generate 3D animation using `OPENGL`. But `OPENGL` requires Window object. Since I am using processing in background to just generate frame, how can I use processing with `OPENGL` to generate animated frames without interactive means without displaying the window.

My sample code

```
import com.hamoid.VideoExport;
import processing.core.*;

public class CircleSketch extends PApplet {

    private VideoExport videoExport;

  public void setup() {
    size(400, 400,OPENGL);
    videoExport = new VideoExport(this, "F:/work/tmp.mp4");
    background(0);
  }
  public void draw() {
    background(0);
    fill(200);
    rotateX(radians(50));
    rectMode(CENTER);
    rect(width/2,height/2, 100, 100);
    videoExport.saveFrame();
  }
}
```

`DisplayFrame` Class

```
public class DisplayFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    public DisplayFrame(){
        this.setSize(600, 600); //The window Dimensions
        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        javax.swing.JPanel panel = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        panel.setBounds(20, 20, 600, 600);
        processing.core.PApplet sketch = new CircleSketch();
        panel.add(sketch);
        this.add(panel);
        this.setVisible(false);
        //this is the function used to start the execution of the sketch
        sketch.init();     
    }
    
    
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       new DisplayFrame().setVisible(false);
    }    
}
```

Any suggestion please???

Comment: OpenGL has nothing to do with processing.Maybe the opposite is true.But it seems to me you should ask the question in connection to Processing framework and not OpenGL.Also your code has nothing to do with OpenGL API

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> how can I use processing with OPENGL to generate animated frames without interactive means without displaying the window.

In short terms: Given the current OpenGL driver models *you can't (as long as you want to use a GPU for rendering).* Period, that's how it is.

If you can live with software rendering (slow), then there's [OSMesa](http://www.mesa3d.org/osmesa.html). Also in the forseeable future there should be changes in the driver models, which allow to use OpenGL in a headless environment. Until then, you need a window of some sort on a graphics environment that actually actively feeds a display output (so it doesn't suffice to start a X11 server and background it).

Comment: Thank you so much for answering. So, how can I run processing with OPENGL in linux server environment. Do I need to install desktop environment like KDE or X11 server will work.

Comment: This is a nice accurate answer(+1). @SumitGupta I would also do a test with a software renderer (Java3D maybe ? ) or converting the 3d coordinates to 2d and drawing in 2d ? Note that PApplets by default will create a window (which you can hide later). If this is an issue, consider using plain java with a software 3d library

Comment: @SumitGupta: You'll need at least a X11 server and drivers for your GPU installed. Depending on your distribution regular users may or may not permitted to start the X server. How to fix it is described here: http://www.x.org/wiki/FAQMiscellaneous/#index2h2 ; once a regular user can start the X server you can use `xinit <full path to your program binary> <options to your program> -- <options to the X server>` launch your program running within the X server. If you have several programs that require X you may want to start some kind of session environment (DJB's daemontools work for that).

Comment: @SumitGupta: Remember that the X server offers another attack surface so if your internet service gets hacked, it may bounce off the X server to elevate its privileges. So you should be security conscious about that.